# Xamarin Forms - TabbedPage - Pass Parameter

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, tabbedpage

I have a TappedPage like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:local="using:MyApp" x:Class="MyApp.AccountPatientPage" Title="Account">
    <local:PatientConditions IconImageSource="user.png" />
    <local:PatientPainKillers IconImageSource="user.png"  />
    <local:PatientPainStory IconImageSource="user.png"  />
</TabbedPage>
```

and here is the code behind:

```
public partial class PatientProfilePage : TabbedPage
    {
        public PatientProfilePage(string username)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

My question is how can I pass the string username to the other pages? Here is an example of one.

```
public partial class PatientConditions : ContentPage
    {
        public PatientConditions(string username)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

Comment: if this is a value that will be consistent and shared throughout the app, it probably makes more sense to create a property on the App object that is visible on all pages

Comment: Its not, just these pages.

Comment: create the pages in code instead of XAML.  Or create a VM for the tabbed page that the content pages will inherit

Comment: Can you show me an example of this @Jason

Answer (score 1):

your pages will inherit their parent's `BindingContext` unless you specify differently

```
// some custom class that contains properties for username and anything 
// else you need
MyViewModel vm;

public PatientProfilePage(string username)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.BindingContext = vm = new MyViewModel(username);
}
```